# How to handle high amount of SQLite requests (multi threaded)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, exception, sqlexception

I am using a method like this to update existing data: ([Docs](http://pastebin.com/WhMy74Ax))
But sometimes (when I get around 10 updates per second) I get this Exception: `java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_BUSY]`  The database file is locked (database is locked)

How can I fix this? I thought `SQLite` would work with `multithreaded` applications.

Another problem is that I have a unique username aswell, before I update something in the table I check if this user exist. If not I create an empty user and start updating like in the method above. But if its too fast I get this error aswell:
`java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]`  Abort due to constraint violation (column username is not unique)
This only happens when I get too many requests aswell.

Comment: SQLite isn't necessarily the right choice for a web site or similar database where there are a lot of simultaneous connections. I'm not sure if that's the case here or not though...?